# Unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Tags: python, pandas, strict

From the code below (Python), I get error

```
"TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'".
```

What is the problem?

```py
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
from fredapi import Fred
fred = Fred(api_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
startdate = dt.datetime(1990,1,1)
enddate = dt.datetime.now()
df1 = pdr.DataReader(['GS10', 'IRLTLT01EZM156N', 'IRLTLT01SEM156N'], 
                     'fred', startdate, enddate)
```

Comment: You need to put the entirety of the error stack in your question.

Comment: I guess it is something from [`fredapi`](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi) module.

Comment: Found a solution myself, I just restarted the Kernel. And then it worked!